# Backbone model destroy function doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I have a backbone model. I just want to simply call the destroy function to call the delete method in controller(asp.net MVC). The delete call occurs but the values that I set for the model doesn't pass to the controller. Can somebody suggest me a solution for calling the destroy function?

Answer (score 1):

A delete operation passes the ID only with no request body. It will do `DELETE /model/:id` by default. If you need to access values from the model in your asp.net server side code, load it from the database before deleting it.